# First file in alphabetical order not copied with rsync

Tags: rsync

I'm using the following command to make a full, recursive copy
of the contents of one directory into another :

`rsync -avzhe /path1/to1/dir1/* /path2/to2/dir2/`

It works as I expect it to, except that the first file (in alphabetical order), be it a directory or a file, is not copied. Every other file gets copied. Why ?

My OS is MacOS 10.14.6 if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make a full copy of the directory `/path1/to1/dir1` called `/path2/to2/dir2`, use

```bsh
rsync -av /path2/to1/dir1/ /path2/to2/dir2
```

There is no point in using compression (`-z`) for a local copy. The `-e` option specifies the command used to establish the network connection (which is why your command fails in copying the first file; `rsync` uses it as the option-argument to the `-e` option), so that should be removed too in this scenario.

Also, don't use `*` at the end of the source path, as that would ordinarily not match any hidden names.  Globbing all names under `dir1` could potentially also expand to a list too long for the command to execute at all.

Just make sure that the source path ends with a slash.  A slash at the end of the destination path makes no difference. Removing the slash from the source path would copy `dir1` inside `dir2`. A slash at the end of the source path makes `dir2` a copy of `dir1`.

Other than that, you may want to use `-H` to make sure hard links are established correctly at the destination and `--sparse` if you know you are copying files that may be sparse (like pre-allocated disk images).

Use `--delete` to also *delete* entries from the destination that is not part of the source file hierarchy.  Use this with caution.  You may want to test run with `-n` (`--dry-run`) first.

Answer (score 9):

The `-e` option needs an argument, so it takes the first filename for that. I'm not sure why you want `-e` as it sets the command to use to connect to the remote, but you are not using a remote. Just remove the `-e`.

Comment: Thanks. I used that command in a remote situation a long time ago, and unthinkingly reused it as is.